# Rails create active record with has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, has-many

I have a rails model which has a has many association as follows

```
class Physician < UserProfile
has_many :state_licenses, inverse_of: :physician, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
validates_presence_of :state_licenses, :message=>"Please select at-least one state license"
```

And in my controller, I am trying to create a new physician with state_licenses as follows

```
  def create
    physician = nil
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      physician = Physician.create(params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :title, :residency_board_status, :residency_specialty_id))
      logger.debug("in physician create")
      params["user"].merge!({ user_profile_type: Physician.name, user_profile_id: physician.id })

state_licenses = params["state_licenses"]

      if (state_licenses != nil)
        state_licenses.each do |state_license|
          physician.state_licenses.create(physician_id: physician.id, state_id: state_license)
        end
      end

      user_record = nil
      super do |user|
        user_record = user
        user.errors.delete(:user_profile)
        physician.errors.messages.each { |field, messages| messages.each {|message| user.errors.add(field, message)} }
      end
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless user_record.persisted? && physician.persisted?
    end

    AdminNotificationsMailer.physician_signed_up(physician).deliver_now rescue nil
  end
```

Even though I am creating a bunch of state licenses on the physician, I still get the validation error to select at-least one state license. How can I ensure that the association of the physician with the state licenses is correctly made during physician creation?

Comment: Can you also please post what data is coming in params['state_licenses']?

Comment: Also when you create state_licenses for a physician you need not give physician_id again.

physician.state_licenses.create(state_id: state_license)

Comment: Thanks Surya. The data inside params["state_licenses"] is an array of strings like this... ["1","2","5","7"]. Plus when I try to create the state licenses on the physician, it gives me an error saying can't be created unless parent is saved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `physician.state_licenses.create(state_id: state_license)` this should work, if it doesnt work then  maybe there is some active record validation error. Please print logger:

`state_license = physician.state_licenses.create(state_id: state_license)
Rails.logger.inspect "STATE LICENSE #{state_license.errors}"`
`
And post the logger statement.